# Android. Java. Шифрование RSA. Зашифровка с заданным ключом

Tags: java, android, криптография, rsa

Всем привет. Нужна помощь с зашифровкой текстовой строки на java. Итак, у меня есть сервер на node.js, на нем храниться заранее сгенерированный приватный ключ.

```
            var net = require('net');
            var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');    
            var key = new NodeRSA('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+
'MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEA0Fr1yKrGhssOXL3ldwX43mDq3Q3rq0tlK7LqAlka9e6fTnHu\n'+
'Ключ\n'+
'2LcEssIqMeCAxsisFjZkhrogdH/exUAvBimkV0ns33IlKzY8Az93xH9baht7\n'+
'-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----');
            var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
            console.log("Server start!");
            socket.on('data',function(chunk){
                    console.log(chunk.toString ());
                    var decrypted = key.decrypt(chunk.toString(), 'utf8');
                    console.log(decrypted.toString());
                    socket.end(chunk);
                });
            socket.on('end',socket.end);
        });
    server.listen(1337);
```

Есть приложение (с заранее сгенерированным публичным ключом) под андроид на java которое должно отправлять на сервер зашифрованную строку. На сервере реализовать расшифровку получилось, использую библиотеку node-rsa. Подскажите пожалуйста какую-нибудь библиотеку или киньте ссылку на пример для реализации шифрования на java. Тот алгоритм который мне удалось найти присылает на сервер какую-то фигню ([B@41e7ff40), которую сервер не может расшифровать и которая вобще не похожа на зашифрованный 2048 битным ключом текст.

Забыл сказать что я пытался менять ключи на сервере и в коде приложения, но на сервер приходило одно и то-же, значит я что-то не так сделал в коде шифрования.
Часть кода отвечающая за шифровку:

```
public static String encryptRSA(String mess){
String pem = //"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                "MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA0Fr1yKrGhssOXL3ldwX4\n" +
                        "Ключ\n"+
                        "Dz0E8irYwH0Md70VrXV6vptdWYl/rhMewmxwqVYI/frow5MeBUYwcwWbgtWzMSxd\n" +
                        "OjjJBaOh41OQlTFOf5v7DwECAwEAAQ==\n"; //+"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(pem, Base64.DEFAULT));
            KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);

        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] encodedBytes = null;

        try {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey);
            encodedBytes = c.doFinal(mess.getBytes());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodedBytes.toString();
    }
```

Добавление от 16.03.

Использовал `return new String(encodedBytes);`, теперь на сервер приходит нечто со смайликами, цветочками и буковками, я так понимаю это utf8(зашифровано слово passsword):

```
8?☻??92↨q??w§?*F?E%W??♠.$♀??>3?cC)??P◄??3/,W-y??i>?X?H]?)?A????L♫?????♠[??¶6?uc
O♠?4<→⌂?♀"??M?9??)X??U??&??5_♥a?
??♫L?:♣?N[P???8???ef???◄⌂C?_k????9???uP0f?T?E????????'?_♀??9[=e♀R"??q►??$ "??qD
w?⌂r?@???▬?q?♠c?↑s&?~xP{???
```

Если не переводить в string то приходит последовательность в шестнадцатеричной кодировке:

```
<Buffer 38 ef bf bd 02 ef bf bd ef bf bd 39 32 17 71 ef bf bd ef bf bd 77 15 ef
bf bd 2a 46 ef bf bd 45 25 57 ef bf bd 3f 06 2e 24 0c ef bf bd ef bf bd 3e 33 ..
. >
```

При переводе на сервере в base64 выходит это:

```
OO+/vQLvv73vv705Mhdx77+977+9dxXvv70qRu+/vUUlV++/vT8GLiQM77+977+9PjPvv71jQynvv73v
v71QEe+/ve+/vTMvLFctee+/vdKJaT7SnVjvv71IXe+/vSnvv71B77+977+977+977+9xL0O77+977+9
77+977+977+9Blvvv73vv70UNu+/vXVj77+9Twbvv700PBp/77+9DCLvv73vv71N77+9Oe+/vc21KVjH
oe+/vVXvv73vv70m77+977+9NV8DYe+/vQrvv73vv70OTO+/vToF77+9TltQ77+977+977+9OO+/ve+/
ve+/vU0IZWbvv73vv73vv70Rf0Ma77+9CO+/vV9r77+977+977+92oY577+977+977+9dVAwZu+/vVTv
v71F77+976Gz77+977+91J7vv73vv73vv70n77+9Xwzvv73WgjlbPWUMUiLvv73vv71xEO+/ve+/vSQg
Iu+/ve+/vXFE77+9e0Pvv70877+9ADJ0eO+/ve+/ve+/ve+/vQZj77+9GHMm77+9fnhQe++/ve+/ve+/
vQ1377+9f3Lvv71A77+977+977+9Fu+/vXE=
```

Выглядит оно довольно странно и не расшифровывается.
 При изменении чего-либо в сифере приложение вылетает.

Comment: [B@41e7ff40 очень похоже на результат функции Object.toString(). Может, вы как-то неправильно преобразуете объекты.

Comment: Это так умиляет, когда выкладывают приватный ключ :)

Comment: @Barmaley реализую генерацию сеансовых ключей так что какая разница)

Comment: Сеансовые ключи не так делаются :) Если в каждом сеансе будете вычислять пару ключей RSA - то вас живьем слопают...

Answer (score 1):

Блочное шифрование (к коим относится RSA) предполагает применение 3-х параметров:

1. Алгоритм
2. Правило выравнивания блоков (padding)
3. Правило сцепления блоков (blockchaining)

Все это хозяйство задается при выборе `Cipher`, например:

```
//читается как RSA с выравниванием PKCS1 и без сцепления блоков (ECB)
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

Если один из параметров не указан, то берется, тот который предусмотрен по умолчанию. Умолчание вообще то разное у разных провайдеров.

Очевидно, что на стороне node.js и Android у вас разные умолчания - оттуда и разночтения.

Вывод: явно укажите то что вам надо - например чисто пацанский `RSA/CBC/PKCS7Padding` :)

Answer (score 0):

Массив байтов объединить в строку методом `toString()` не получится.

Замените

```
return encodedBytes.toString();
```

на

```
return new String(encodedBytes);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684665/java-byte-array-to-string-to-byte-array